# Appcelerator SDK 5.4 Android Calendar permission on Android 6

Tags: android, permissions, calendar, appcelerator

I've read a really lot of posts yet, but the problem still occurs...

My app needs calendar permission, and this wil work fine till Android 5.
In my trap.xml in the permissions ar set as followed:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

When I try to set the permission like I found on Jira:

```
function calenderTask() {
    if (Ti.Calendar.hasCalendarPermissions()) {
        showCalendars(Ti.Calendar.selectableCalendars);
    } else {
        Ti.Calendar.requestCalendarPermissions(function(e) {
            if (e.success) {
                showCalendars(Ti.Calendar.selectableCalendars);
            } else {
                Ti.API.error(e.error);
                alert('Access to calendar is not allowed');
            }
        });
    }
}

function showCalendars(calendars) {
    for (var i = 0; i < calendars.length; i++) {
        Ti.API.info("Calender: "+calendars[i].name);
    }
}

calenderTask();
```

only after a fresh install on the device (Samgung S7, Android 6) there is some action when I place an alert in the code.

The next run it looks like the code is ignored.

And... most important of all, there is no permissions set.

When I manually set the permission in the settings of my device, the app works fine.

Please is there somebody with a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to find a better way of checking Calendar permissions on Android 6.
Meanwhile, I'm using this code to send the user right to the app settings on a dialog:

```
var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog();
dialog.message = 'Please check your calendar permissions';
dialog.cancel = 1;
dialog.buttonNames = ['Settings', 'Cancel'];
dialog.addEventListener('click', function(e){
var intentData = {action: "android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS", data: "package:" + Ti.App.getId()};
var flags = [ Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY, Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS];
if (e.index === 0){
 win.openIntent(intentData, flags);
}
});
dialog.show();
```

I hope it helps a bit...

Comment: Hi Carlos, Thank you, I'll try it as soon as I'am at home.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution/workaround for my problem that the calendar permission was not asked for.

In the settings section of the device I removed the permissions by hand by the specific app. Now I did a reset on all settings of the installed app's and then the question is asked on the device when I start the particular part  of the app.
Thus just remove the permissions and delete the app from the device is not enough!

I've used the part of code that I listed before, that from Jira.

So, for the moment my problem is solved (I think) and the app is asking for the needed permissions after first install.

Carlos, thanks for your comment, and I hope you can do something with my investigations too.